# Addition with checkboxes

Tags: jquery

How can I to add the cost that is `190 + 150` from given code and displays on another `div`, let say `div` total?

I have already made a variable and stored the respective cost, my target is that when a user checked the checkbox (I have approx 10 checkboxes), the respective prices get added to the total and when unchecked it automatically substracts. Can anyone kindly give me a hint as to how to go about it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //var pdf=$('#result').html(" -PDF Document");

    $('#1').click(function() {
        //var row = $(this);
        if (($(this).attr('checked')) == 'checked')
            $('#result').append("-PDF Document <html><span style=float:right>$190</span></html>");
        else
            $('#result').text("");
    });

    $('#2').click(function(){
        if (($(this).attr('checked')) == 'checked')
            $('#result2').append("-Video <html><span style=float:right>$150</span></html> ");
        else
            $('#result2').text("");
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you please also post your HTML.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/BA5rX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

JS:

```
function refreshPrices() {
    var currentTotalValue = 0;
    $("#results div").each(function() {
        if (!isNaN(parseInt($(this).find("span").text().substring(1)))) {
            currentTotalValue += parseInt($(this).find("span").text().substring(1));
        }
    });
    $("#totalValue").text("$" + currentTotalValue)
}
```

To use it, store all your "`result*`" containers in a container, which will make the output easier to iterate through with jQuery [since only one major selector (`"#results"`) is needed to grab the results in all of the "`result*`" containers].

```
<div id="results">
<div id="result">
</div>
<div id="result2">
</div>
</div>
```

And whenever the user interacts with a checkbox, `refreshPrices()` should be called.

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
                        <td style="width: 13px">
                            <input id="1" type="checkbox" name="" onClick="" />

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h4>PDF Document</h4>
                            <p>
                                Already have your own menu or flyer? Include it in your App
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="cost" id="pdf-cost">£99.99 per document</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 13px">
                            <input id="2" type="checkbox"/>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h4>Video</h4>
                            <p>
                                If you've already got videos on your website, these can be included within your App too.
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td class="cost">£149.99 per video</td>
</tr>
<table>
<br>
<br>
<div id="totalValu">Total Value: <span id="totalValue">$0</span></div>
<div id="results">
<div id="result">
</div>
<div id="result2">
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#1').click(function() {
        //var row = $(this);
        if (($(this).attr('checked')) == 'checked') {
            $('#result').append("-PDF Document <html><span style=float:right>$190</span></html>");
        }
        else {
            $('#result').text("");
        }
        refreshPrices();
    });

    $('#2').click(function() {
        if (($(this).attr('checked')) == 'checked') {
            $('#result2').append("-Video <html><span style=float:right>$150</span></html> ");
        }
        else {
            $('#result2').text("");
        }
        refreshPrices()
    });
});​
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BA5rX/7/

Answer (score 3):

have a look at this fiddle.. so that you can have some idea.... it does what i think you have asked for..

**javascript**

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){
  var $val=$(this).val();
  var total=$('#total').html();
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    var finaltotal=parseInt($val) + parseInt(total)
  }else{
    var finaltotal=parseInt(total) - $val 
  }

      $('#total').html(finaltotal);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Azzr/1/

**UPDATED**

WITH YOUR EXAMPLE..

http://jsfiddle.net/BA5rX/4/

**NOTE**: i created a div with total value in it...

```
<div id="total">1000</div>
```

**LATEST UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/5YZp5/2/

Comment: Thanks,i am trying to merge http://jsfiddle.net/5YZp5/ as well as this code,but only working one code,not working simultaneous,may be click funtion

Comment: can u make the jsfiddle of the merged code (including the html).. let me see why isn't that wroking... :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion based on your html - I fixed your invalid IDs and added a class instead. Also I calculate onload as well in case the page is reloaded and the checkboxes are not cleared. I take the value from the table cell minus the leading pound char

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/476qq/)

```
function calcTotal() {
  var total = 0;
  $(".check:checked").each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).parent().siblings(".cost").text().substring(1));
  });            
  $("#totalDiv").html("£"+total.toFixed(2))

}

$(function() {
    calcTotal(); 
    $(".check").on("click",function() {
       calcTotal(); 
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can amend your HTML so that you add a `class` to each `checkbox` and a `data-price` parameter which contains the price you can make your jQuery very simple like this:

```
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(".checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        total += parseFloat($(this).data('price'));
    });
    $("#total").html(total.toFixed(2));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BA5rX/6/)